# What if after getting paykey for website paypal api, transaction will complete by user with their paypal account?

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, e-commerce

Take an example , I have website where i have integrated paypal api with shopping cart and if any user proceed for transaction and after that will received payKey from paypal for your api call. and then you need to redirect your page to paypal. But in between or after redirect if user/customer will go to their own account in paypal and complete that transaction from paypal admin panel. So how will I(my website) get notified that transaction is completed for my initialized (originated from my website payment page) payment for my purchases.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the return url in the paypal form that you send to paypal before the user do the payment. The input must have `name=return`, you also can assign return url if the user cancel the payment.

```
<?php 
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="'.$dir_ok.'"> ';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="'.$dir_error.'"> ';
?>
```